# Is there any restriction/limitation against female passengers who travel to the Arab countries of the middle east by these countries?

Tags: visas, legal, middle-east, female-travellers

I was searching for visa rules of some *Arab countries* in the middle east which may **limit** or **prohibit** women (in relation to marital situation, age, male accompaniment, etc) to travel to their countries. Like Oman for example.

Arab countries of the middle east officially: Iraq, Syria, Saudi Arabia, Kuwait, Oman, Yemen, UAE, Qatar, Bahrain, Jordan, Lebanon, Egypt and the State of Palestine which is an autonomous government but not an independent country yet and is a non-member observer in the UN.

Do you know if there are any rules like this in these countries or not?

Comment: You are correct, I don't get your question. In particular why you limit it to Arab countries only. Why not include Iran, Turkey and Israel?

Comment: Because in Iran,Israel and Turkey there is not such rules against foreign female travelers who travel to these countries . And another matter it is my choice in question. It is not by you to decide about what I should ask here and should not if they are all on topic by FAQ or ask for my motives. It is a question and you can provide an answer if you know if not leave it for the others. At finally comments are for improving questions not for asking why a user is asking a special question! I hope it helps!

Comment: Perhaps focusing on the term "country" is not necessary. These are all "places", including Palestine, with degrees of Arabic + Muslim culture where travellers may well expect the culture to have effects on laws and regulations they may need to comply with.

Comment: Please avoid lengthy discussions in comments -- keep them focused on the question itself, and bring extended dicussions in chat.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes, There are:**

**Oman:**

Chinese, Russian and Ukrainian nationals may obtain visit visas following the same procedures provided that they are part of tourists groups arriving to the Sultanate through a local tourist agent or a hotel or as a family. In the case of groups, the number of females must not exceed the number of males. Source: [wikitravel.org](http://wikitravel.org/en/Oman)

**Saudi Arabia:**

Due to the strict requirements of Saudi Arabia, women entering the Kingdom alone must be met by a sponsor or male relative and have confirmed accommodation for the duration of their stay. Additionally, entry may be refused to any visitor judged as behaving indecently, according to Saudi Arabia law and tradition. Source: [visabureau.com](http://www.visabureau.com/worldwide/saudi-arabia-visa.aspx)

Note that it’s extremely difficult for young, single women to enter the country unless it’s clear that they’re closely related to expatriate workers. Business women will encounter serious obstacles to entry unless they’re members of a Saudi family or have the sponsorship of a powerful Saudi national. Source: [justlanded.com](http://www.justlanded.com/english/Saudi-Arabia/Saudi-Arabia-Guide/Visas-Permits/Visas)

**Qatar:**

For longer stays, visas must be arranged by having a sponsor. Unmarried women under the age of 35 will have a hard time in procuring a visa for a lengthy stay, as the country seems to fear that their safety and well being cannot be guaranteed. Source: [wikitravel.org](http://wikitravel.org/en/Qatar)

**Syria:**

Citizens of Arab countries do not require visa, except unaccompanied Moroccan women below 40 years old. Source: [wikitravel.org](http://wikitravel.org/en/Syria)

**Lebanon**:

Female travellers can also obtain a visa on arrival provided they have not formerly taken a job as artists; in that latter case, they must gain approval in advance from Lebanese immigration. However, this approval is not required for:
a. Wives of Lebanese citizens who have proof of the relationship;
b. Wives of Palestinian refugees in Lebanon who have proof of the relationship;
c. Wives of Syrian citizens accompanied by their husbands;
d. Travellers arriving with their parents, brothers or children provided they have proof of the relationship; Source: [visados.com](http://visados.com/en/visa-for-Lebanon)

**UAE:**

A visa may not be issued to a woman under 30 years old travelling without her husband or father.Normally, there are no age-related restrictions. However, the UAE Government may sometimes impose restrictions for young lonely women. But a woman under 30 will have a visa issued without problems if she is travelling with her husband or father having the same last name. The problem can also be solved by booking and paying for a room in a 5-star hotel. The rejection risk will be much lower in that case! Source: [palmarytravel.com](http://palmarytravel.com/country/uae/en.htm)

**Bahrain:**

All other visitors require one of the following visas. Note that, although certain visas are theoretically obtainable on arrival in Bahrain, young single women should be sure to arrange them in advance, as they will come under scrutiny at the point of entry owing to the recent increase in the number of prostitutes attempting to enter Bahrain! Source: [justlanded.com](http://www.justlanded.com/english/Bahrain/Bahrain-Guide/Visas-Permits/Types-of-Visa)

Comment: The most popular answer is not correct! I know that at least in Dubai, there is no restriction on woman traveling to their country.

Comment: It has been suggested by another user (wrongfully posted as answer instead of comment) that the info here on Dubai/UAE is wrong. In fact I can't find any mention of this [on the travel advice from the UK foreign office](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/united-arab-emirates/entry-requirements)

Comment: After living in UAE for 8 years, I can categorically tell you that the UAE information is incorrect.   Not your fault.  A single woman under 30 can get a tourist visa just as easily as a single man under 30, and work visas can go to anyone that the company sponsors - single, female, under 30, etc.  The only restrictions are nationality-based, and not related to gender at all.

Answer (score 6):

From my first hand experience few years ago and many of friends' experiences earlier and later, **Lebanon would refuse visas to unmarried women ages 17 to 30**.

According to travel guides, it's theoretically possible to get that visa going through very complicated and lengthy bureaucratic process, which makes it impractical for young women tourist. It's also been said that in this case their choice of entry point is limited to Beirut Airport. Everybody else just gets visa-on-arrival, regardless if they come through airport or land crossing. Later was used to be typical issue, because Lebanon was typical day trip while visiting Syria (obviously not a tourist destination nowadays due the civil war).

Comment: Interesting sad information which I didn't know! :(